# OCaml syntax confusion

Tags: syntax, functional-programming, ocaml

When I first began using the in statement I thought it was pretty straightforward and made sense. However, these code examples made me question how well I understand them.

```
let fun1 x = let fun2 y = y + 1 in fun2(x);;
val fun1 : int -> int = <fun>
```

I think this can be thought of as declaring fun2, and then applying it to call fun2 with a variable `x` that you get from fun1.

```
let sum1 i = let sum2 j = i+j in sum2;;
val sum1 : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

This one confuses me much more and raises more questions. I don't really know how to interpret this. Is it that sum1 was declared to be used in sum2? If so why does `in` apply to the outer function and not the inner function like it did in the first example?

Any help in interpreting these code snippets would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as an `in` statement. There are `let` definitions of the form `let [rec] pattern = expression {and pattern = expression}` and `let` expressions of the form `let [rec] pattern = expression {and pattern = expression} in expression` (where `[]` means "optional" and `{}` means "zero or more"). So `in` is merely a part of the syntax of `let` expressions.

> Is it that sum1 was declared to be used in sum2?

No. `sum2` is defined to be used inside `sum1` just like in your first example. `sum1 i` simply returns `sum2` as its result. Another way to write it without giving a name to the function being returned would be:

```
let sum1 i = fun j -> i + j
```

Or even:

```
let sum1 i j = i + j
```